# Parenting Object Instancer into Matrix of Flipping Polygon Faces

Tags: animation-nodes

It might have been answered but not sure. Anyways:
- I setup this Flipping Poly Face, basic one
- I made duplicate of Suzanne head and place it on the Center of each Face

Need to do parent to each Poly Face, but my setup is not working as expected. Probably Matrix basic, but need some pointer.[image]

[image]

In short:
How to parent object into Poly Face ensuring when the Face is rotated, the Object follows like Vertex Parenting?

Thanks!

Comment: hmm I think the problem is that only the vertex locations are transformed by the Transform Polygon node.... This will change in the future hopefully. for new you can try to transform the Polygon Center separately using the Transform Vector node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I made a mistake up there where I am using the SOURCE Mesh Data to place and rotate the Instance copy where in fact I can easily use the TARGET Mesh Data and Polygon Info node to have the effect I need.

[image]

Case Closed.

Comment: Can you accept your answer to mark the question as solved?